# Creating custom functions with multiple arguments

Tags: programming, function-construction

I am hoping that this isn't a stupid question so feel free to vote it for closure. Google failed somehow.

I want to define a custom function (more complicated than the usual `f[x_] := someExpression`) that performs several tasks (taking elements of a set, performing computations, etc.) before giving an output. I don't want to run the whole bunch of codes repeatedly.

Is there a way of defining such a function?

What I have in mind is, say a program in R, which goes like

```
function_name <- function(arg1, arg2, ..., argn){
    routine 1
    routine 2
    routine 3
    ...
    Output to be returned
}
```

EDIT: In view of the comment that this question is somewhat vague, I am posting part of the code below:

```
Final = {{1}};
For[hn = 0, hn < 7, hn++;
 rp = {0}; fn = hn;
 For[fk = 0, fk < fn, fk++;
   Clear[r, v, w, p, q, z, x, n, k, t, res, pt];
   v[z_] := Sum[q^d, {d, 0, z - 1}];
   n = fn; k = fk; t = {}; For[i = 0, i < (n - k), i++;
     For[j = -1, j < k, j++; t = Join[t, {j}];]];
   t = KSubsets[t, (n - k)];
   For[i = 0, i < Length[t], i++;
     t[[i]] = Sort[t[[i]]]];
   t = Union[t];
```

The code is quite long (sloppy programming). I just want the whole thing to be given a name so that I can just type that name of that function and vary the arguments.

Comment: Maybe if you could say something more definite about the function you want to see, we could be a little more helpful... in short, *what's your actual problem*?

Comment: Multiple statements, exactly.

Comment: You should read the docs for `Module` and come back with a more concrete question

Comment: Hope this clarifies things up. I want to write a program (this might be the appropriate word for it), which is like a function in the sense that it takes arguments and returns an output. The program performs tasks (computations, assigning variables, etc) and I would like to find a way of writing such a program, and by running the program by simply typing the name and the arguments. The usual method of defining a function f[x_]:= doesnt seem to work for my purpose.

Comment: Also, try to use more [tag:functional-style] for coding instead of procedural routines and `For` loops, as it is really rewarding in *Mathematica*.

Comment: So, something like `Permutations[]`? `Subsets[]`?

Comment: In R, the body of a is placed inside curly braces. The last value inside the braces is what the function returns when it is evaluated. For example, xyz<-function(m,n){x=set containing n elements; y=set containing m elements;z=cross product of x and y;z}. In mathematica the body of a function is not enclosed in {} and it returns the value after the = sign. (Or am I missing a key mathematica feature?)

Comment: Ok, Kenjo, you are coming from R, MMa works quite a bid different. I can only repeat what R.M. has suggested already. Read up on `Module` and `List` in the manual to gain a basic understanding of how MMa works. I also suggest to read the 'Core Language' document of MMa.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The original question asked how to do something like the following in Mathematica

```
function_name < - function (arg1, arg2, ..., argn) {
  routine 1 
  routine 2 
  routine 3 
  ... 
  Output to be returned}
```

So, yes!  You could do something like this:

```
functionName[arg1_, arg2_, arg3_ (* '_' following a name identifies a function argument *)] := 
 Module[{local1, local2, local3 (* Local variables *)},

  local1 = Join[arg1, {a, a, c, a, e, b, d}];
  local2 = Sort /@ local1;
  local3 = local2 + arg1 * arg3; 

  {local1, local2, local3} (* Output to be returned *)
  ]
```

So again, yes you can define a function that has:

- any number of arguments,
- any number of local variables,
- routines that set local variables, and
- return any, all, or any combination of the local variables.

Note one can also define local functions inside a function then use them just as you would any other.  A simple if kind of silly example follows:

```
functionName[arg1,arg2]:= 
  Module[{loca1,local2,localFunction}, 
  localFunction[localAgr1_,localArg2_]:=localAgr1^localArg2;
  local1=localFunction[arg1,arg2];
  local2=local1 * 2;
  local2]
```

Simply put Mathematica gives you extensive flexibility.

As others have commented look up functions, `Module`, `Block`, and functional programming.  It will reward you with precise, elegant, and powerful code.

Comment: This is exactly the structure of the code that I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  Welcome to the site.  Stick around if you can.  The real experts on this site have serious chops and they contribute lots of time and attention.  I learn new things everyday.  I don't know of a better learning community anywhere.

Answer (score 14):

You've already had a lot of feedback suggesting that some time with a basic introduction to programming would be useful. I'm going to provide an answer anyway, in the hope of providing a “teachable moment” for other beginning Mathematica users.

My first comment is that the code you have posted is not complete: the two outermost `For` loops do not have closing square brackets. This will be clear from the pink syntax highlighting in the Mathematica front end. Even after I fixed this and a few other things up, your version of the code doesn’t actually return anything. The definition of a function `v[z_]` isn't used elsewhere in your code, so it is hard to work out what you are trying to do. And since you are using [`KSubsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/KSubsets.html), don’t forget you need to evaluate the following first.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

My second comment echoes those of others: you almost never need loops in Mathematica. There is usually another, more efficient and concise way. (The exception is if you are going to compile the code using a C compiler, but you are not at that stage.) István’s suggestion to explore the [functional-style](/questions/tagged/functional-style) tag is a good one. In particular, have a look at [this summary of alternatives to looping constructions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8).

Now, to the specifics of your code. The commenters who suggested wrapping your multiple statements in [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) were exactly right. This is a [scoping construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/8) which will allow you to localize your intermediate variables so their definitions don’t leak out to affect other calculations. You then don’t need that `Clear` statement. The last line is indeed returned, as long as there is no semicolon suppressing output.

I am now going to go through some obvious issues with the code. Take this line:

```
For[i = 0, i < Length[t], i++;  t[[i]] = Sort[ t[[i]] ] ]
```

What you mean is, “I want every sublist in `t` to be sorted”. You would be much better off just using [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), which “maps” a function onto each element of a list. The shorthand version of `Map` is `/@`, so:

```
t = Sort /@ t
```

Here’s another example.

```
For[j = -1, j < k, j++; t = Join[t, {j}]
```

All this is doing is creating a vector from -1 to `k`. So just kill that loop and try:

```
t = Range[-1,k-1]
```

Another issue in your code is that, at the point that you invoke `KSubsets`, you are outside the two inner `For` loops. So $n = k$, and you are finding `KSubsets` of length zero, i.e. empty sets.

A final point I’d make is that you are defining variables like `n` and `k` that are just mirroring the iterators in your `For` loops. This is a waste of time in a language like Mathematica and just makes your code harder to read.

Making all the above changes results in something like the following:

```
KenjosFunction[kk_Integer?Positive] := 
 Module[{r, v, w, p, q, z, x, n, k, result = {}},
  For[n = 0, n < kk, n++;
   For[k = 0, k < n, k++;
    For[i = 0, i < (n - k), i++;
     result = 
      Join[result, 
       Union[Sort /@ KSubsets[Range[-1, k - 1], (n - k)]]]];
    ]];
  result 
   ]
```

There are still three nested `For` loops which I haven’t cleaned up, but it is much cleaner and easier to read. It also actually gives a result, though I have no idea if it is the one you want:

```
KenjosFunction[4]
(* {{-1}, {0}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-1}, {0}, {1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 
  1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1}, {0}, {1}, {2}} *)
```

Further simplifications you could consider, depending on your real code, includ eliminating the `For` loops by defining  a single nested  `Table` and using `Flatten` to get the right dimensions. I leave this as an exercise for you.

Comment: Sorry for posting an incomplete code (the one I posted was even less than half the code I wrote). I never thought you would actually dissect the code I posted, since all I really needed is a way of creating a function with multiple statements. As a beginner in Mathematica with background in C, my tendency is to use LOOPs and IFs and I'm surprised there are actually shorter (and I believe) quicker alternatives.